# The shift keys type letters X and W?

Tags: keyboard

On pressing my <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> I'm getting "x" and on pressing the <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> i'm getting "w".

Just now, pressing the <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> I'm getting this: "xxxxxxxxxxx" and on the right one "wwwww".

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you let us know what version of Ubuntu you're running?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the settings of the keyboard, maybe you set that the keyboard language is "1" (language set) and your language is "2" (your language) =D

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Ubuntu doesn't know what kind of keyboard you have.

In a terminal, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. Pick one of the generic boards the describes yours, and make sure to select the right country of origin.